# how to return only one different element in list in python

Tags: python

I have a list of elements and only one (odd number or even number) is different than others and I want as a result its index in the list.

For example:

```
nums = [2, 4, 6, 8, 7] or nums = [1, 3, 4, 5]
#how using only "for" loop not def (it is too difficult for me yet) do it?
for i,num in enumerate (nums):
    if num % 2 == 1 and ... # I was thinking here of using a count function (I do not know how to tell python that in the same time it should be unique element
        print (i)
    elif if num % 2 == 0 and ...
        print (i)
```

Please explain simply because I am very much a beginner in Python.

Comment: You are looking for what in python is called list comprehensions. Read up on those. Here is an example: `[ind for ind, i in enumerate(nums) if not i % 2]`

Answer (score 2):

It's really hard to understand the scope of the problem, but if you simply want a majority vote (as in all numbers vote for the group being even or odd, then you might do something like this:

```
nums1 = [2,4,6,7,8]
nums2 = [2,1,3,5,7]
def get_one(nums):
    nums_bin = [i%2 for i in nums]
    if sum(nums_bin)>1:
        return nums_bin.index(0)
    return nums_bin.index(1)
print nums1, get_one(nums1)
print nums2, get_one(nums2)

# outputs 
# [2, 4, 6, 7, 8] 3
# [2, 1, 3, 5, 7] 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nums = [2, 4, 6, 8, 7]

#With the following line you take modulo 2 for each element so nums will become [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
nums = [x%2 for x in nums]

#you still need to figure out, if the majority of elements was even or odd
#you can do that by checking the sum of the array. If it is 1, all but one element were even, if it is len(nums)-1 all but one were odd.
sum_of_nums = sum(nums)


for i in range(len(nums)):
    #If the sum is ==1 you are looking for the one element that is 1
    if nums[i] == 1 and sum_of_nums == 1:
            print(i)
    #If the sum is len(nums)-1 you are looking for the one element that is 0
    if nums[i] == 0 and sum_of_nums == len(nums)-1:
        print(i)
```

Now regarding the don't use `def`:

The `def` is used to define a function similar to what you know from mathmatics. `f(x)=x+1` will work for `f(1)=2 , f(2)=3` in a similar way you `def = define` a function that takes an input (`Math -> the x, here -> an array of Integers`) and does something to it (`Math -> Add 1, here -> find the element`)

The syntax is `def functionName (inputParameter):`

for the code above:

```
def yourFunction (nums):
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        #If the sum is ==1 you are looking for the one element that is 1
        if nums[i] == 1 and sum_of_nums == 1:
                print(i)
        #If the sum is len(nums)-1 you are looking for the one element that is 0
        if nums[i] == 0 and sum_of_nums == len(nums)-1:
            print(i)
```

You can now do the following:

`nums1 = [2, 4, 3]`
`nums2 = [3, 5, 8]`

and just call:

`yourFunction(nums1)` and it will print `2`

`yourFunction(nums2)` and it will print `2`

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain the question step by step, and as requested, I will try to avoid defining functions or list comprehensions at first, and try to explain how to go from `for` to list comprehension or defining functions.

We start with our list `nums`, and we define two empty lists. In one we will store the positions of the even numbers in `nums` and in the other the position of the odd ones:

```
#nums = [2, 4, 6, 8, 7] 
nums = [1, 3, 4, 5]
odds = []
evens = []
for i,num in enumerate (nums):
    if num % 2 == 1:
        odds.append(i)
    elif num % 2 == 0: 
        evens.append(i)
```

The, we will print the list of length 1:

```
if len(odds)==1:
    print odds[0]
elif len(evens)==1: # or else:
    print evens[0]
```

There is an `elif` instead of an else to check that there is indeed only one number different to the rest, but it could be substituted by an `else`.

---

Now to simplify and make the code a little more pythonic.

The creation of the odds and evens list can be written in the same line, using list comprehensions. Thus, the `for` loop can be simplified to only 2 lines:

```
odds = [i for i,num in enumerate(nums) if num % 2 == 1]
evens = [i for i,num in enumerate(nums) if num % 2 == 0]
```

Then, if you have more than one list to check, it will be interesting to wrap all the commands up to the print in a *function*. With this, simply calling this function defined by you, all the commands will be executed at once.

Functions are defined with the `def` command, followed by `function_name(input1,input2...):`, at the end, there is the option of placing a line containing `return output1,output2...`. In this case, there is only one input, the list of numbers, and one output, the index of the *odd/even one out*, therefore:

```
def oddeven_one_out(num_list):
    odds = [i for i,num in enumerate(nums) if num % 2 == 1]
    evens = [i for i,num in enumerate(nums) if num % 2 == 0]
    if len(odds)==1:
        result = odds[0]
    elif len(evens)==1:
        result = evens[0]
    return result
```

Now, the function can be called for each list:

```
nums1 = [1, 3, 4, 5]
print oddeven_one_out(nums1)
nums2 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 7]
print oddeven_one_out(nums2)
```

The function defined has one little problem though, which is that if the user makes a mistake and enters a list where all numbers are even, the variable `result` will not be defined, and `return` will raise an error.

This can be easily solved and will help in understanding the `return` command. When the function encounters a `return`, it leaves, without executing the code that may be below. Using this behaviour, we can redefine the function:

```
def oddeven_one_out(num_list):
    odds = [i for i,num in enumerate(nums) if num % 2 == 1]
    if len(odds)==1:
        return odds[0]
    evens = [i for i,num in enumerate(nums) if num % 2 == 0]
    if len(evens)==1:
        return evens[0]
```

Now the function checks if there is only one odd number, and if it is the case, returns its position, otherwise checks if the different one is even and if so returns its position. In addition, if the user calls `oddeven_one_out([1,3,5,7])`, the result will be `None` because the function does not return any value.